# Show PyGTK Window on all virtual desktops/workspaces

Tags: python, pygtk, workspace

I am working on a [timer](https://github.com/iyonius/Yet-Another-Timer) which should after a certain time show a popup window. I want to force the user to accept the fact that the time is up.

I would like to set the window to be visible on all workspaces. I am able to set that property manually in a window manager but the application should do that.

How to ask a window manager to make a window "show on all workspaces"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call [`my_window.stick()`](http://developer.gnome.org/pygtk/stable/class-gtkwindow.html#method-gtkwindow--stick).